# Formal alternative to 'Hopefully'

Tags: single-word-requests

Does there exist a one word alternative to 'Hopefully' in the sense of 'I am hopeful that' or 'I hope that' which can be used in a formal document? I believe 'hopefully' is rather informal or common in spoken usage rather than written text, although some source like [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hopefully) tend to disagree.

Comment: If _hopefully_ is informal, it's because the occasions on which the thought is likely to be expressed are informal.

Comment: The objections some people (prescriptivists) have to 'hopefully' meaning 'It is to be hoped that' usually centre around the claim that 'the word's only proper usage is as an adverb meaning 'with a hopeful attitude' as in ' "Can I have a tenner?" he asked his dad, hopefully.' Usage would indicate they're fighting a rearguard action. However, I'd agree that there is a faint hint of informality about the modal-pragmatic-marker usage. See DougM's answer on its non-use in legal documents.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I think you have a point. In formal documents one rarely just hopes. What I had in mind was a letter to a superior where one explains some contingency in the future or something of that nature.

Answer (score 1):

More formal substitutions for "Hopefully" vary entirely on where it appears within your correspondence.  (You wouldn't use "hopefully" or any synonym for a law or contract.)  Consider the following:

> Dear Karnn;
>
> I have received your question, and *hope* that this answer meets your needs.  **Hopefully**, you will find it a superb answer and accept it as such.
>
> *Hopefully*,
>
> DougM

Since "hope" is a rather informal message not always appropriate to business communication, we can substitute it entirely.

> Karnn:
>
> I have received your question, and *believe* that this answer meets your needs.  **Ideally**, you will find it a superb answer and accept it as such.
>
> *Sincerely*,
>
> DougM

Of course,  the conversational style of writing demonstrated above is in itself rather informal, and for a more-formal correspondence all ambiguity and polite niceties would be entirely eliminated, leaving nothing but clear declarations.

> Karnn:
>
> I have received your question and written this answer in response.
>
> Doug M

Answer (score 0):

You can use "hoping that + clause".

Comment: That _really is_ informal. But it's just nudged me into identifying _existential here_: 'Here's hoping that we have the results by the end of next month'. Which is even more informal.

Comment: @ DougM.  *an* superb?  I'm seriously interested in knowing if this is common usage.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully is not inherently informal. What you may be worried about instead is that you are conveying a sense of insecurity about some fact or result. In formal writing, it often makes more sense to make the extent of that insecurity explicit.

```
'Hopefully, we should have results by the end of next month'
```

Is very fuzzy.. While

```
'We expect results by January 31st'
```

sounds formal. Getting rid of fuzziness often has the side-effect that the word 'hopefully' goes away as well.

Comment: I disagree with that first sentence. Regardless of whether one accepts the "prescriptivist objections" flagged up in [@Edwin's comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149071/formal-alternative-to-hopefully#comment308249_149071), and/or DougM's point that in *more formal correspondence all ambiguity and polite niceties would be entirely eliminated*, the fact remains that all such uses of ***hopefully*** are inherently informal. If you *had* to admit the concept, you'd say something like *"It is to be hoped that..."* in a formal context.

Comment: I agree with DougM that there is a degree of informality about even 'It is to be hoped that'. It wouldn't be used in a legal document either - it's non-precisionist.

Comment: I would agree with the comments, but because of the reasoning behind it. I guess you can't cut the word loose from its meaning, I was trying to say the word did nothing wrong - it has always been a good word... but I guess that's optimistic.